# How to uninstall Jenkins war packages completely from list

Tags: uninstall, jenkins

Long back I have installed Jenkins and later uninstalled also, now I am tring to reinstalling it but could not login `localhost:8080` and also even though I have uninstalled Jenkins still I could see `jenkins.war` packages in list. I need to remove this.

I have tried all this:

```
sudo apt-get remove jenkins.war
```

or

```
sudo apt-get purge jenkins.war
```

or

```
sudo apt-get remove jenkins
```

Still not working, showing error like:

```
E: Unable to locate package jenkins.war'
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'jenkins.war'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'jenkins.war'
```

By using this command:

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove jenkins
```

getting like:

```
package 'jenkins' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Comment: How did you install this software? If you did not install it with `apt`, then you cannot remove it with `apt`.

Comment: *i could see "jenkins.war" packages in list* --- Which list? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1336033/edit) the question.

Comment: installed using command wget URL(Jenkins.war) and then ran with the command java -jar Jenkins.war

Comment: that doesn't install it, that just runs it.  Follow the install instructions for jenkins on their site.  https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/linux/